# Can not ssh login to bitbucket.org

Tags: ssh, bitbucket

I can't push to bitbucket.org anymore.

I have checked the public key is still at bitbucket.

As suggested elsewhere I tried `GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v' git push`
and got this result.
I wonder if some options have changed with the latest update to ssh

Everything seems fine (to me), yet git push fails with `Authentication failed.`

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u4, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [2406:da00:ff00::22cd:e0db] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_1.1.15 49a70a8 app-155
debug1: no match: conker_1.1.15-49a70a8 app-155
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none  
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikJYKwbHaxvSc0ojez9YXaGp1A
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:13
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
Authentication failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

```

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to be using the root account locally?

Comment: Done that for years.

Comment: And your access to the repo in question hasn't changed?

Comment: Not what I know of. Last commit was in August. I am admin on the bitbucket account.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the public key was already on bitbucket, and the public and private keys seemed to match, using some suggestions here, I made a new keypair, and made a special key for git@bitbucket.org in /etc/.ssh/config

Now I have my access back.